# Why do I need a cast to access the actual value from base class?

Tags: c++, enums, base-class

I have a class `B` derived from `A` where there's a member called `type` which I want to access from a method from class `B` but instead of actual value I get a `0` but if I cast `this` to `A` inside `B` method it will work fine, like this: `((A*)this)->type` so it's give me the actual value instead of `0`. Can someone explain that? I wrote a short version of my actual class to give an code example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

enum TYPE
{
    T_INTEGER = 2,
  T_FLOAT = 4
};

struct A
{
  enum TYPE type;
  A(enum TYPE);
  A();
  int print();
};

struct B : A
{
  enum TYPE type;
  B(enum TYPE);
};

struct Number : B
{
  union
  {
        int intvalue;
        float floatvalue;
  };
  Number(int);
    int print();
};

A::A() { }

A::A(enum TYPE Type)
    : type(Type)
{
}

B::B(enum TYPE kind) :
  A(kind)
{
}


Number::Number(int v)
  : B(T_INTEGER),
    intvalue(v)
{
}

int Number::print()
{
    printf("type = %d\n", type); // output: type = 0 (wrong)
    printf("type = %d\n", ((A*)this)->type); // output type = 2 (correct) but why do I need cast?

    switch(((A*)this)->type)
    {
  case T_INTEGER:
    return printf("%d", intvalue);
  case T_FLOAT:
    return printf("%g", floatvalue);
    default:
        assert(0);
    }
}

int main()
{
    Number *n = new Number(2);
    n->print();
    delete n;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared a member variable

```
enum TYPE type;
```

in both class `B` **and** `A` but your `B` constructor never initialises its **own** variable with that name - it just passes it to the `A` constructor which initialises `A::type`

```
B::B(enum TYPE kind) :
   A(kind)
{
}
```

Thus the `B` member is never initialised. It is not clear why you have added a variable of the same name and type again in the derived class `B` but my guess is that perhaps you did not intend this and rather just want a single variable of this type in the base class `A`

When you have this situation with same variable name and type in both a derived and base class, the derived class member shadows the base class member - this is why accessing `type` from your `Number::print()` method refers to the `B` member rather than the `A` member. Obviously then casting `this` to `A*` accesses the `A::type` member.

Comment: Thanks. In fact, in my actual code `B` derived from another class that's derived from `A` too, which includes a member called `type` too, the actual source of error. That's why I didn't figured out before

Answer (score 1):

You declared the member variable `type` in both `A` and `B`. But `B` inherits the member variable `type` from `A`. This means every object of type `B` contains *two* `type` variables: `A::type` and `B::type`. Since `Number` is derived from `B`, it too contains both `A::type` and `B::type`. When you use the unqualified name `type` in a member function of `Number`, it resolves to `B::type` since `B` is lower on the inheritance hierarchy than `A`. This member is not initialized by your constructors; only `A::type` is initialized. But `((A*)this)->type` refers to `A::type`. (Side note: prefer `static_cast<A*>(this)` to `(A*)this` in this case.)

The solution here is probably to remove the declaration of `type` from the definition of `B`. (But I'm not sure what you're trying to do.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the Number variable type, because that is what you are printing.

```
Number::Number(int v)
  : B(TYPE::T_INTEGER),
    intvalue(v)
{
    this->type = TYPE::T_INTEGER;
}
```

Like that, that initializes the local type so it will print 2.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast because both structs A and B have an attribute with the exact same name and type.  How else would the compiler be able to give you the correct value?  If you don't cast then you get the one associated with B that you have never initialized, so it is zero just by dumb luck.  It is completely separate from the one that is declared/defined within class A.  My guess is that the variable in B hides the one in A, and the only way to get to the one in A is to do the cast and explicitly tell the compiler what you want.  Get rid of the one in B since you are not setting it anyway, and it should work fine.